# How to customize Finder's Share menu?

Tags: finder, automator, menu-bar, dropbox

Is there a way to add custom services to Finder's Share menu?

I have created an automator service to copy selected files to my Dropbox directory (similar to [this](http://www.podfeet.com/wordpress/tutorials/how-to-create-an-automator-script-to-back-up-to-dropbox/)).

I enabled this service in the keyboard preferences.

Now I want to add this service in the Share menu rather than having it in the general contextual menu.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but I would suggestion following :

1. Copy your automator service in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ShareKit.framework/Versions/A/PlugIns/`
2. rename it `Servicename.sharingservice`
3. Now edit `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ShareKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SHKServicesOrder.plist` by adding your service. (CFBundleIdentifier in Info.plist + function name)

Comment: I tried just copying the Facebook service and renaming it, and adding it to the plist file, but it didn't show up anywhere.

Comment: I also tried logging out and back in, but nothing changed. I have a feeling that the particular share services need to be requested by the app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible, at least in a "conventional" way. That contextual menu is populated by adding accounts to the Mail, Contacts & Calendar preference pane, not sure if its even possible to build a workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120829111756236) tip, it looks like you need to edit:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ShareKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SHKServicesOrder.plist
```

Don't have a Mac in front of me to try it.